# Pullback is not exact

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a map of schemes. Then we have the "quasicoherent" pullback which takes $F \in Qcoh(Y)$ and gives $f^* F = \mathcal{O}_{X} \otimes_{f^{-1} \mathcal{O}_{Y}} F$. This functor $f^*: Qcoh(Y) \to Qcoh(X)$ is right exact but not left exact in general since it involves tensoring by $\mathcal{O}_{X}$ and $X$ need not be flat over $Y$. For example, take the point $0$ inside $\mathbb{A}^1_{k}$, then we have the inclusion $0 \to (x) \to k[x]$ which can be thought of as a sequence of sheaves on $\mathbb{A}^1_{k}$ and it becomes the zero map $(x)/(x)^2 \to k[x]/x$ after the restriction to the point.

So, my first question is the following: why do people study $R^i f_*$ and do not study $L^i f^*,$ that is left derived functors of $f^*$? Probably, there should be a simple reason but I don't know it.

I'm also confused about my computation: denote $i: 0 \to \mathbb{A}^1_{k}$ the natural inclusion. From one hand, $i^* F$ should be equal to the stalk at the point zero due to the last lemma of Tag [0099](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0099), i.e. the localisation of the corresponding $k[x]$-module $M$ at the maximal ideal $(x)$. On the other hand, $i^* M = M \otimes_{k[x]} k = M/xM$ which is the fiber at the point $0$. For example, if $M = k[x]$, then the first one is $k[x]_{(x)}$ and the second one is $k$. What is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0. Your definition of quasicoherent pullback is wrong: it should be $\mathcal{O}_Y\otimes_{f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_X} f^{-1}F$.
1. People do study the derived pullback! Just not as much or as early as derived pushforward. Derived pushforward is basically sheafifying "taking cohomology", which is something that is useful to know how to do basically as soon as you know what cohomology is, while derived pushforward doesn't solve the same level of problems.
2. The $i_x^*$ that Stacks talks about in that hint is for the inclusion of the locally ringed space $\{\{x\},\mathcal{O}_{X,x}\}$ in to $X$. You are using the locally ringed space $\operatorname{Spec} \kappa(x)$, the spectrum of the residue field. These are very different.

Comment: 0. Sure.
1. Ok, it's nice to hear it!
2. So, in general if I have a closed subscheme Z of X with the reduced scheme structure and I restrict (using pullback) a sheaf on X to Z then what I get is a "fiber" of F along Z and not a "stalk", right?

Comment: Yes, that's how I'd use the words fiber and stalk here.